# after install mageto2.4 i have screen with EOF?

Tags: magento2

after install magento2.4.2
I go to browser and I go to my local host "alldata.magento.com"
and what I have is "EOF" in blank page
[image]

Comment: After reviewing your question it is hard to determine if this is a magento issue or if this is an issue with your local environment. can you please be clearer in regards to your environment and steps taken.

Comment: Have you check the console and magento log file for the real error?

Comment: install magento from official web site [link](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?_ga=2.199925550.1271481890.1635236353-985686067.1635236353) "Build version:ver 2.4.3-p1, format:magento open source2, include sample data: true" and I followed these [steps](https://www.thecoachsmb.com/6-steps-to-install-magento2-4-2-on-xampp-windows-using-composer/) to install, and this [photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1skhRezxTpKjUqBIwHTC7Q9y3lHmmluMe/view?usp=sharing) for console from browser if this help

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in the case of the character where it should be Uppercase letter
I need Change `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy` but I write `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\copy`.